# I need help sorting a multi-dimensional array by date

Tags: php, sorting, date, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm having trouble sorting this multi-dimensional array by date. I want $list_array to be sorted by the 'date'

```
$list_array = array
    (
    array("date"=>"2020-01-02", "address"=>"1629 W Main St", "city"=>"Ville Platte", "client"=>"Anette Albert", "agent"=>"Michelle Rockwood", "office"=>"Gardner Realtors", "price"=>"445"),
    array("date"=>"2019-02-03", "address"=>"201 La Rue Rhiems", "city"=>"Duson", "client"=>"William Myers", "agent"=>"Teresa Pastor", "office"=>"District South", "price"=>"375"),
    array("date"=>"2019-01-07", "address"=>"1402 Southport Blvd", "city"=>"New Iberia", "client"=>"Jose Villatobos", "agent"=>"Rickey Romero", "office"=>"Keller Williams", "price"=>"550"),
    array("date"=>"2019-01-08", "address"=>"900 S. College Dr, Ste 100", "city"=>"Lafayette", "client"=>"Susan D'Picard", "agent"=>"John Allen", "office"=>"Keller Williams", "price"=>"325"),
    array("date"=>"2017-12-02", "address"=>"1629 W Main St", "city"=>"Ville Platte", "client"=>"Anette Albert", "agent"=>"Michelle Rockwood", "office"=>"Gardner Realtors", "price"=>"445"),
    array("date"=>"2016-02-03", "address"=>"202 La Rue Rhiems", "city"=>"Duson", "client"=>"Robert La'Rue", "agent"=>"Suzanne D'Ambrosio", "office"=>"Van Eaton", "price"=>"365"),
    array("date"=>"2019-01-07", "address"=>"1405 Southport Blvd", "city"=>"New Iberia", "client"=>"Bob Barker", "agent"=>"Rickey Romero", "office"=>"Keller Williams", "price"=>"560"),
    array("date"=>"2019-01-08", "address"=>"900 S. College Dr, Ste 103", "city"=>"Lafayette", "client"=>"Susan Johnson", "agent"=>"Fred Arse", "office"=>"Keller Williams", "price"=>"315")
    );

    usort($list_array, 'date_compare');

}

function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['date']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['date']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}
```

I want the array to be sorted like the following array.

```
$list_array = array
    (
    array("date"=>"2016-02-03", "address"=>"202 La Rue Rhiems", "city"=>"Duson", "client"=>"Robert La'Rue", "agent"=>"Suzanne D'Ambrosio", "office"=>"Van Eaton", "price"=>"365"),
    array("date"=>"2017-12-02", "address"=>"1629 W Main St", "city"=>"Ville Platte", "client"=>"Anette Albert", "agent"=>"Michelle Rockwood", "office"=>"Gardner Realtors", "price"=>"445"),
    array("date"=>"2019-01-07", "address"=>"1405 Southport Blvd", "city"=>"New Iberia", "client"=>"Bob Barker", "agent"=>"Rickey Romero", "office"=>"Keller Williams", "price"=>"560"),
    array("date"=>"2019-01-07", "address"=>"1402 Southport Blvd", "city"=>"New Iberia", "client"=>"Jose Villatobos", "agent"=>"Rickey Romero", "office"=>"Keller Williams", "price"=>"550"),
    array("date"=>"2019-01-08", "address"=>"900 S. College Dr, Ste 100", "city"=>"Lafayette", "client"=>"Susan D'Picard", "agent"=>"John Allen", "office"=>"Keller Williams", "price"=>"325"),
    array("date"=>"2019-01-08", "address"=>"900 S. College Dr, Ste 103", "city"=>"Lafayette", "client"=>"Susan Johnson", "agent"=>"Fred Arse", "office"=>"Keller Williams", "price"=>"315"),
    array("date"=>"2019-02-03", "address"=>"201 La Rue Rhiems", "city"=>"Duson", "client"=>"William Myers", "agent"=>"Teresa Pastor", "office"=>"District South", "price"=>"375"),
    array("date"=>"2020-01-02", "address"=>"1629 W Main St", "city"=>"Ville Platte", "client"=>"Anette Albert", "agent"=>"Michelle Rockwood", "office"=>"Gardner Realtors", "price"=>"445")
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `array_multisort` (see the third example on the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)), passing it as the first array to sort the `date` field (extracted using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)):

```
array_multisort(array_column($list_array, 'date'), $list_array);
```

Note that since your dates are in `YYYY-MM-DD` form, you don't need to convert them to sort them.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/cGTLs)

Comment: Works perfect! You saved me lots of time. Thank you so much!